# Using filename substitution -- How to search for files with letters in this order?

Tags: command-line, bash

So I need to find all files which have d, o, and g in the filename. The letters do not need to be side by side (aadaaoaagaa would be a correct filename, aaoaadaag would not be a correct filename). It does not matter if the letters are uppercase or lowercase (aadaaOaag is a correct filename, as is aaDoGa.

How would I use filename substitution on the terminal command line to list all of the files like this? Preferably without using loops or anything too advanced. All I have been introduced to so far is filename substitution characters (*,?,[])

Comment: Just `ls *[dD]*[oO]*[gG]*` is not good enough?

Answer (score 2):

To list them when you are in the directory where those files are in, you can use, as Nykakin said in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350991/using-filename-substitution-how-to-search-for-files-with-letters-in-this-orde#comment449740_350991) the following command:

```
ls *[dD]*[oO]*[gG]*
```

or, if you want each file on its own line, you can use:

```
printf '%s\n' *[dD]*[oO]*[gG]*
```

or, using grep:

```
ls | grep [dD].*[oO].*[gG]
```

Comment: ls *[dD]*[oO]*[gG]*    The problem with this is, I think it makes it possible for the letters to get mixed up since there is the * between everything, meaning those could also referance a d, D, o, O, g or G. They have to be in order, it cannot be like oDog because the o has to come after the d

Comment: @JohnStacen Well, you didn't said nothing about the cases where an "o" or "O" is before these letters in your question. You can eliminate these occurrences using `grep -v`. For example: `ls *[dD]*[oO]*[gG]* | grep -v [oO].*[dD]`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want all those filenames with a `d`, an `o` and a `g`, in any case (upper or lower). Radu Rădeanu gave you an answer that works for the letters occuring in the order `d`-`o`-`g`. For example `aaGaaaoaaDaa` will not be found. You could alter his solution using the six possible permutations as, e.g.,

```
ls *[dD]*[oO]*[gG]* *[oO]*[gG]*[dD]* *[gG]*[dD]*[oO]* *[oO]*[dD]*[gG]* *[dD]*[gG]*[oO]* *[gG]*[oO]*[dD]*
```

(setting `shopt -s nullglob` before is a good idea).

This becomes a bit messy, so you might want to also use `shopt -s nocaseglob` so that *the match is performed without regard to the case of alphabetic characters* (quoted from the *Bash Reference Manual*) as:

```
$ shopt -s nullglob nocaseglob
$ ls *d*o*g* *o*g*d* *g*d*o* *o*d*g* *d*g*o* *g*o*d*
```

Another option is to use the *find* command as, e.g.,

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -iname '*d*' -iname '*o*' -iname '*g*' -type f
```

The `-maxdepth 1` option is to limit to the current directory and not its subdirectories and `-type f` to limit the search to regular files. Change these options to fit your needs. `-iname` is for a case-insensitive search on the name (using glob patterns). Don't forget the quotes!

One advantage of *find* is that you'll be able to `-exec` stuff if you need to perform any operation on these files, e.g., renaming them, or appending stuff to them, etc. Another advantage is that if you have a huge number of such files, the globbing will take ages, and might even overflow the maximum number of arguments allowed. *find* will be alright, whatever the number of files is.

Hope this helps!

**Edit.** It seems I missed the *in this order* part in your title. Hahaha. Well, then the *find* command would simply be:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -iname '*d*o*g*' -type f
```

and the `ls`/`printf` solution would be:

```
$ shopt -s nullglob nocaseglob
$ ls *d*o*g*
$ printf '%s\n' *d*o*g*
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use Perl for this:

```
perl -le 'print for grep {/\A[a-cefh-np-z]*d[a-fh-z]*o[a-z]*g[a-z.]*\Z/i} <*>'
```

**Explanation**

- `<*>` is magical: it returns the result of globbing the pattern `*` from the current directory.
- `grep{}` only returns those items of the glob matching the criteria inside it.
- `print` outputs the result of `grep` one item per line due to the `-l` option.
- The single criterion used for `grep` is that the file name consist exactly of:

  - any number of letters in the set `[a-cefh-np-z]` (the alphabet minus
    `o` and `g`)
  - the letter `d`
  - any number of letters in the set [a-fh-z] (the alphabet minus g)
  - the letter `o`
  - any number of any letter whatsoever
  - the letter `g`.
  - any number of letters or a period (for extensions).
- The `i` modifier is applied to the regex criterion to ensure the match is case-insensitive as required in the question.

I know this isn't exactly what you asked for, but I believe Bash wildcard patterns are too simple to handle this task.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at the problem would be to keep only filenames for which once eliminated every character outside of D,O or G, the result would be exactly `DOG`, case insensitive.

This could be done in shell with search-replace-test instead of wildcards:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nocasematch 
shopt -s nullglob
for i in *
do
  if [[ ${i//[^dogDOG]/} == dog ]]; then 
    echo $i;
  fi;
done
```

Comment: `for i in \`ls\`` is just plain wrong and broken. Use `for i in *` instead.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: I've changed to `for i in *` for spaces in filenames but one could argue that since `*` expands as `*` when the dir is empty, it's also incorrect strictly speaking to get the directory contents. It doesn't matter much here, though.

Comment: To avoid that, use `shopt -s nullglob` or, to have an explicit error use `shopt -s failglob`. Globbings should always be used with either of these options. Since you're already `shopt`ing, you might as well replace the `shopt` line with `shopt -s nocasematch nullglob`.

Comment: Also, avoid using backticks! use `$(...)` instead. Moreover, to remove all the letters `dogDOG` from a variable, you can use parameter expansions: `${i//[^dogDOG]/}`. It's much nicer and doesn't require the external tool `tr`. I'd hence write `if [[ ${i//[^dogDOG]/} == dog ]]; then`