# How would I display the lines that do not have certain letters?

Tags: command-line, bash, grep

How would I display the lines that do not contain certain letters? This is what I have already tried unsuccessfully to show the lines that do not consist of an a or b:

```
egrep *[^ab]* filename
```

Comment: You have this answer in [one of the comments](http://askubuntu.com/questions/350991/using-filename-substitution-how-to-search-for-files-with-letters-in-this-orde#comment449935_351019) on a previous answer to another question of yours. You should read them! Also see `man grep`; it can learn you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Just use invert matching:

```
grep -v "[ab]" filename
```

**Source:** [man page for grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep)

Comment: Don't forget to quote the pattern to grep. If the current directory happens to have the two files named `a` and `b`, the command will turn into `grep -v a b filename`, which does something different than intended. So: `grep -v '[ab]' filename`